# Rails JS templating still valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used this method explained in a Railscast episode when I can use a .js.erb file as a template to add data via an ajax call to my page:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

It worked fine but just wondering, is this method still the right way to accomplish this or is there a better way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Is it still officially endorsed? **Yes**. Is it the right way? Very questionable as it makes an absolute mess of your application and JavaScript. It is the only ways if you want to use Rails server side templating in your JavaScript though (with no effort) and kind of the goto way to splinkle some ajax on top of otherwise classical applications.

Comment: Its absolutely the wrong way to teach noobs ajax though as you just get this tangled mess of context switching where it just becomes less and less clear what is happening on the server and what it happening on the client and the separation of concerns just goes out the window.

Comment: "is there a better way of achieving the same thing" - there are many other ways to do ajax. Many of them better than creating server side views that alter the state in the client.

Comment: Thanks for that.  What alternatives would you recommend?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is.